# Captured variable in C# function with a List<> parameter

Tags: c#, linq, list, closures

I have the following sample codes.  I don't like to have lTest being captured and get the same value as lRet.  I tried to introduce "`List<Test> lTest1 = lTest0;`" in the function AddMore2Test.  It does not work.  What is the proper way to do this?

Thanks!

Codes -

```
private void Test(){
  List<Test> lTest = GetInitTestList();

  List<Test> lRet = AddMore2Test(lTest);
}

private List<Test> AddMore2Test (List<Test> lTest0) {
  List<Test> lTest1 = lTest0;

  return lTest1.Where(…);
}
```

Comment: It's not at all clear to me what you're trying to do, or what you mean by "it doesn't work". If you could write a short but *complete* program and tell us what the actual result is, along with the desired result, that would make it a lot easier to help you.

Comment: I think he is trying to deep clone the list and the objects inside.

Comment: Don - Welcome to stackoverflow, it always helps to post detailed questions and to reread the question your self.  Pretend you were going to answer your own question.  Ask yourself is there enough information there for a stranger to even understand what I am asking.

Comment: Thanks Guys. This board always gives me quick and good answers even though the question is not clear. I appologize for the confusing question. I tried to make my question clear by rewriting it from my large applicatin but missed something. Matt Greer's lTest.ToList() is what I look for. That eliminates the reference problem (No a closure problem I thought initially).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So at the end of it all you want `lTest` to contain an initial set of values, and `lRet` to contain those initial values, but with a bit of filtering applied? The problem is you are dealing with references, so ultimately everything is pointing at the same list. A quick, simple fix is to just do this:

`List<Test> lRet = AddMore2Test(lTest.ToList());`

Comment: +1 - I could not understand the question, but how in the heck someone else did is beyond me. :)

Comment: But my answer doesn't really work, since AddMore2Test returns a List, and he is using LINQ, he has to be calling ToList() on the IEnumerable LINQ gave him, so he should have two distinct lists already.

Comment: Passing lTest.ToList() gets me the desired short list lRet. lRet and lTest seems not point to the same list. But after I change some fields in an item of lRet. The corresponding fields in lTest change to the same value also. Does each underneath item in lRet and lTest still point to each other? If so, how to solve this problem?

Comment: Yes, a list is just a collection of references. So when you create a new list against an existing one, both lists will point to the same objects (unless the objects are value types). If you want two distinct lists each with their own distinct objects, then you will need to roll that yourself. Look into `IClonable` as a start (although that has drawbacks). I also recommend sitting down with a good C# book and really understanding how references work, that will help reduce a lot of confusion.

Answer (score 2):

I think you will probably want to use the **List** class' **AddRange(IEnumerable list)** method on the lRet instead of assinging the value:

```
lRet.AddRange(AddMore2Test(lTest))
```

EDIT: in the comments it was pointed out that lRet hadn't yet been initialized, so here is a viable change:

```
var lRet = new List<Test>(AddMore2Test(lTest));
```

Comment: lRet is not initialized, so he can't call methods on it. But he could do `lRet = new List<Test>(lTest); lRet.AddRange(AddMore2Test(lTest));`

Comment: ahh yes good catch. Even more compact would be lRet = new List<Test>(AddMore2Test(lTest)); though that may not be as readable